# Why this step is not working?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a test case with Selenium Java to login and then
 click an item from a dock menu.
It login alright but it do not click on the dock menu item.
This is the code I wrote. can any tells me what is wrong?

```
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.findElement(By.id("content")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("sign-in")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("_58_login")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("_58_login")).sendKeys("basand");
driver.findElement(By.id("_58_password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("_58_password")).sendKeys("pass");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("DockMenuFrame")));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("APP. POS. TM.")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='docMenuForm:j_id46_Function_850010408']/span")).click();
```

Comment: what kind of error is coming on running of this code?

Comment: There is no error, It is just don't click on that frame.
Is it possible, that this frame is under another frame that need to be selected first?

Comment: yes it might be possible, check value of tabindex and build xpath on bases of tabindex for findelement.

Comment: If the element was in an iframe, you'd get a no element exception.  It's possible there are multiple inputs, but the first one it finds is not visible or enabled. Try findElements on that xpath, and see how many results there are.

Comment: use `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By...()))` to see if the element is really clickable before actually clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

problem could be with your SwitchTo().Frame() statement..webelement overload version seems to use a previously found element. In my code, I am having to use
Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent() to go to toplevel frame and then switchframe(s) by the element heirarchy before trying to select an element.